# Passing Kivy Widget to another class

Tags: python, widget, kivy, kivy-language

I am building a dynamic user interface using Python and Kivy. Because I need to add and remove widgets dynamically I want to use a separate class to handle adding and removing widgets from a GridLayout. I called this class LayoutManager.

The GridLayout is defined in my kv-File (id: "config_box_layout"). Inside my root widget class in my python code I am referencing the GridLayout via id. This is working properly. This reference is passed to the LayoutManager in the constructor. I tried passing it via ObjectProperty or GridLayout.

The problem is that I always end up with this kind of error if I try to remove widgets from the Layout:

`'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'remove_widget'`

If I try to remove a widget in the save-method inside my Tab class using config_box_layout.remove_widget(some newly created Label) it's working properly.

I think the problem is that Kivy and all the kv-widgets are weakly-referenced and handling those references over to other classes seem to be not the intended use case.

I try to seperate classes to avoid doing all the coding stuff in one big fat main Layout class.

Looking forward to any help! :)

main.py

```
import kivy
from util.layoutManager import LayoutManager

from kivy.app import App

kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from functools import partial

class ChooseDirectoryDialog(FloatLayout):
    add = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)
    save = ObjectProperty(None)

class Tab(TabbedPanel):

    config_add_src = ObjectProperty()
    ingest_layout = ObjectProperty()
    configManager = ConfigManager()
    config_box_layout = ObjectProperty()
    layoutManager = LayoutManager(config_box_layout)

    def add_src(self):
        content = ChooseDirectoryDialog(cancel=self.cancel, save=self.save)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Add Source", content=content,
        size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def cancel(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def delete_source(self, description, widget):
        self.configManager.delete_source(description)
        self.remove_source_from_ui(description)

    def remove_source_from_ui(self, description):
        self.layoutManager.remove_configuration(description)

    def save(self, srcpath, destpath, description):
        desc_label = Label(text=description)
        desc_label.size_hint_y = None
        desc_label.height = 30
        self.config_box_layout.add_widget(desc_label)

        srcpath_label = Label(text=srcpath)
        srcpath_label.size_hint_y = None
        srcpath_label.height = 30
        self.config_box_layout.add_widget(srcpath_label)

        destpath_label = Label(text=destpath)
        destpath_label.size_hint_y = None
        destpath_label.height = 30
        self.config_box_layout.add_widget(destpath_label)

        deleteButton = Button(text="Quelle löschen")
        deleteButton.size_hint_y = None
        deleteButton.height = 30
        deleteButton.bind(on_press=partial(self.delete_source, description))
        self.config_box_layout.add_widget(deleteButton)

        self.layoutManager.add_configuration(description, 
        desc_label, srcpath_label, destpath_label, deleteButton)

        self.configManager.add_source(description, srcpath, destpath)

        self._popup.dismiss()

    def copyToDestination(self, srcpath, destpath):
        pass


class AutoIngest(App):
    def build(self):
        return Tab()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Builder.load_file('autoingest.kv')
    AutoIngest().run()
```

autoingest.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<Tab>:
    do_default_tab: False
    config_add_button: add_button
    config_box_layout: config_box

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Konfiguration'
        TabbedPanel:
            tab_width: 200
            do_default_tab: False                
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: 'Quellen verwalten'
                StackLayout:
                    orientation: "lr-tb"
                    padding: 10
                    Button:
                        size_hint: .2, .1
                        id: add_button
                        text: 'Quelle hinzufügen'
                        on_press: root.add_src()
                    GridLayout:
                        id: config_box
                        cols: 4
                        Label:
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: 30
                            text: "Bezeichnung"
                        Label:
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: 30
                            text: "Quell-Pfad"
                        Label:
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: 30
                            text: "Ziel-Pfad"
                        Label:
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: 30
                            text: "Aktionen"

<ChooseDirectoryDialog>:
    text_input: text_input
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            text: "Bezeichnung"
        TextInput:
            id: text_input
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            multiline: False
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            text: "Quellverzeichnis auswählen"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: source_chooser
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            text: "Zielverzeichnis auswählen"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: destination_chooser

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Add"
                on_release: root.save(source_chooser.path, destination_chooser.path, text_input.text)
```

layoutManager.py

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class LayoutManager:

    #I alrey tried to pass the GridLayout itself. This didn't work either.
    def __init__(self, configlayout: ObjectProperty):
        self.configurations = {}
        self.configlayout = configlayout

    def remove_configuration(self, description):
        widgets = self.configurations.get(description)
        for x in widgets:
            self.configlayout.remove_widget(x)

    def add_configuration(self, description, *widgets):
        self.configurations[description] = {'widgets': widgets}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the `Tab` instance `ids` have not been setup when your lines:

```
config_box_layout = ObjectProperty()
layoutManager = LayoutManager(config_box_layout)
```

are executed, so `config_box_layout` is not yet set.

You can force the creation of the `LayoutManager` to delay until the `ids` are created using `kivy.clock` in the `build()` method of the `App`:

```
class AutoIngest(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.setup_layoutManager)
        return Tab()

    def setup_layoutManager(self, dt):
        self.root.layoutManager = LayoutManager(self.root.config_box_layout)
```

Also, the line:

```
layoutManager = LayoutManager(config_box_layout)
```

can be removed from the `Tab` class.

Once that is working you will discover issues in your `remove_configuration()` method of `LayoutManager`.

Comment: I decided to change my overall App architecture so I no longer need a LayoutManager class. All Layouts now have their own classes and have their own methods inside those classes.